# How to distinguish between enclosing and nested type parameters using Reflection in .NET?

Tags: .net, generics, reflection

When I have a nested type like this:

```
public class MyOuter<T>
{
    public class MyInner { }
}
```

How do I tell, using Reflection on `typeof(MyInner<int>)` that the type parameter `T` is declared on `MyOuter` and not on `MyInner` ? When I call `typeof(MyOuter<int>.MyInner).GetGenericArguments()` it returns an array with `typeof(int)` and so does `typeof(MyOuter<int>).GetGenericArguments()`.

Comment: The nested types "inherit" the generic parameters from its parent type and you cannot avoid this so you will have to subtract the types inherited from the parent. The "inherited" parameters comes first.

Comment: Hmm, OK. I found that `Type.FullName` contains the number of type arguments, e.g. `MyOuter\`1`, but is there an easier way to get that than parsing the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the decompiled il of your example [(taken from tryroslyn)](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#f:%3Eilr/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgFkEB5YNAJwB4AVAPmwG9sMYTHzEyFarQYIAkhAio2MfjAC+2NUA==):

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit MyOuter`1<T>
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .class nested public auto ansi beforefieldinit MyInner<T>
        extends [mscorlib]System.Object
    {
    }
}
```

You can see that `T` is in fact also declared on the inner type. When you use reflection to get the declaring type of the generic parameter of the inner type:

```
var arg = typeof(MyOuter<int>.MyInner).GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetGenericArguments()[0];
Console.WriteLine(arg.DeclaringType);
```

you will get

```
MyOuter`1+MyInner[T]
```

And that is the correct result, since `T` is declared on the inner Type.
Now it should be clear that the information you are seeking is not directly available, because it does not exit.

But the good news is that you can take the in the comments suggested approach, that could look something like this:

```
var outerArgs = typeof(MyOuter<int>.MyInner).DeclaringType.GetGenericArguments();

var innerArgs = typeof(MyOuter<int>.MyInner).GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetGenericArguments();

var realInnerArgs = innerArgs.Skip(outerArgs.Length);

Console.WriteLine( string.Join( ",", realInnerArgs ) );
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing something like this, but using the number of arguments in `FullName` after the \`.